# File Date Created Newer than Modified Date

Tags: filesystems

We have noticed a file come through a work flow which initially involves uploading the file from the clients computer to our server which the application there moves the completed file to a holding folder and then another application picks it up parses video information from it then moves it to a new folder. 
After the entire flow completed it was noticed that Last modified date was older than when the file was even uploaded through the website and the date created was set to the time it was uploaded. 
by the way the two dates were almost 24 hours apart.

any idea how this could happen>

Comment: timezone settings. unsynced system time.

Answer (score 2):

It could have something to do with the way the files are processed, where the modified time is left to the time where the contents of the file changed, but the created time is when the file in the new location was created.

This happens, for example, when you download a zip file and unzip the contents. The created time is the time you extracted the archive, but the modified time is the time when the author last updated the contents. At least, that's what happens to me.

Keep in mind that time stamps on files are just properties of the file. Usually the OS takes care of updating them for you. But they can be changed at will [if you know how](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-the-last-modified-date-creation-date-and-last-accessed-date-for-files-and-folders/).